# 1st and 2nd derivatives of $x\sqrt{9-x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Do I start with the power rule? I know to rewrite it as $x(9-x)^{1/2}$ and if I use the power rule I get $\sqrt{9-x}/2(9-x)^{3/2}$ and I have no idea if that's right, and then I need to find the second derivative.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the **[Product Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule)**. You need to find the derivative of $ (9-x)^{1/2} $ and the derivative of $x$ and apply the rule. I will not finish this for you since I want you to learn and try it!

Comment: When I tried the power rule it went to 1/2(9-x)^{-3/2}(x)+(9-x)^{1/2}(1) which simplified to sqrt(9-x)/2(9-x)^{3/2}. Is that correct?

Comment: @chloe [Check it out.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+xsqrt%289-x%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can approach it in two ways. You can put the $x$ into the radical:

$$x \cdot (9-x)^{1/2} \Rightarrow (x^2)^{1/2} \cdot (9-x)^{1/2} \Rightarrow (9x^2-x^3)^{1/2}$$

You can now use chain rule to get the derivative:

$$\frac12(9x^2-x^3)^{-1/2}(18x-3x^2)
= \frac{18x-3x^2}{2\sqrt{9x^2-x^3}}$$

For the second derivative it's a bit more annoying since you'll have to use quotient rule...

The other approach is using product rule:

$$x \cdot \frac12(9-x)^{-1/2}(-1) + \sqrt{9-x} \cdot 1$$

The second derivative is a bit easier then.